# Step Size in Gradient Descent for a Non Convex Function with Vanishing Hessian

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, upper-lower-bounds, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to minimize the function $f(X) = \|A - XYY^TX^T\|_F^2$ where the gradient of $f$ follows the bound given belew where $A,X,Y \in R^{n \times n}$

$$\|\nabla f(X_1) - \nabla f(X_2)\|\leq L\|X_1-X_2\|^n_F,\ \forall X_1,X_2, $$

To solve the above problem I am trying to perform gradient descent but the Hessian of the function is 0, hence I a am not able to decide the step size.  I posted a question about hessian here [Bound on hessian when Lipschitz gradient is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165062/bound-on-hessian-when-lipschitz-gradient-is-bounded/3165091#3165091). I not able to get bound on the step size so that gradient descent does not diverge.